# Generic Repository add custom method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I'm trying to create a library with a Generic Repository for later use in my MVC App. The code is as follows...

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
}

public interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T>
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IAuditableEntity
{
    int? UsuarioId { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AuditableEntity<T> : Entity<T>, IAuditableEntity
{
    public int? UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}   

public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> GetByUsuarioId(int usuarioId);
    T GetById(int id);
    T Add(T entity);
    T Delete(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
    void Save();
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
   where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected DbContext _entities;
    protected readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _entities = context;
        _dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbset.AsEnumerable<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> query = _dbset.Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
        return query;
    }


    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByUsuarioId(int usuarioId)
    {
        // NO SÉ COMO IMPLEMENTAR ESTE METODO!!!!!
        return null;
        // NO SÉ COMO IMPLEMENTAR ESTE METODO!!!!!
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbset.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual T Delete(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And these are some of my classes POCO...

```
   public class Documento : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }        
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}

public class Gasto : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    public int? TaxiId { get; set; }        
    public int TipoGastoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public double Importe { get; set; }
    public int Kilometros { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual Taxi Taxi { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoGasto TipoGasto { get; set; }
    public virtual PartidaTarjetas PartidaTarjetas { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tarea> Tareas { get; set; }      

    public int? PartidaTarjetasId { get; set; }

    public Gasto()
    {
        Tareas = new List<Tarea>();
    }
}   

public class Nivel : Entity<int>
{
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string PaginaInicio { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    public Nivel()
    {
        Usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
    }
}
```

My problem is that it will not implement the method...

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByUsuarioId(int usuarioId)
    {
        // NO SÉ COMO IMPLEMENTAR ESTE METODO!!!!!
        return null;
      // NO SÉ COMO IMPLEMENTAR ESTE METODO!!!!!
    }
```

It is a generic method which should only return results when is IAuditable type..., must be something as well...

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByUsuarioId(int usuarioId)
    {
        return _dbset.FindBy(c => c.UsuarioId == usuarioId);
    }
```

Can you help me?,
Thanks.

Hello C Bauer ...

Note that ...

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
}

public interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T>
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IAuditableEntity
{
    int? UsuarioId { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AuditableEntity<T> : Entity<T>, IAuditableEntity
{
    public int? UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And my GenericRepositry is ..

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
```

Then now ¿?

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : ¿¿ ??
```

Comment: Are you just trying to ensure that the generic parameter `T` implements `IAuditable`? That's the purpose of generic constraints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx.

Comment: For example Documento.cs implements AuditableEntity<int> ...

Comment: @JesúsSánchez Hi Jesus, you should avoid editing other users into your answers. Instead add a comment to answer that addresses the problem you have with their code.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know how do it

Comment: Yes, but how can i insert code??

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a typed repository extension class so that it only works on `IRepository<IAuditable>`:

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IAuditable> GetUsuarioById(this IRepository<IAuditable> repository, int id)
        {
            return repository.FindBy(audible => audible.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

Edit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace StackOverflowPlayground
{
    class JesusPlayground
    {
        public JesusPlayground()
        {
            var auditableRepo = new AuditableRepo();
            auditableRepo.GetUsuarioById(1);

            var otherRepo = new OtherRepo();
            //otherRepo. (does not have GetUsuarioById


            var auditableRepoNotUsingTheActualClass = new GenericRepository<IAuditable>();
            auditableRepoNotUsingTheActualClass.GetUsuarioById(1); //still works!
        }
    }


    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IAuditable> GetUsuarioById(this IRepository<IAuditable> repository, int id)
        {
            return repository.FindBy(audible => audible.Id == id);
        }
    }



    public class OtherRepo : IRepository<OtherType>
    {
        public IEnumerable<OtherType> FindBy(Expression<Func<OtherType, bool>> expr)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class OtherType
    {
    }

    public interface IAuditable
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr);
    }

    public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class AuditableRepo : IRepository<IAuditable>
    {
        public IEnumerable<IAuditable> FindBy(Expression<Func<IAuditable, bool>> expr)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I then used two repositories? ... GenericRepository and AuditableRepo??

Comment: Well, that depends on how your application is architected. I've always used repository to standardize the way data access is built. You can just as easily do: `var auditableRepoNotUsingTheActualClass = new GenericRepository<IAuditable>();`               `auditableRepoNotUsingTheActualClass.GetUsuarioById(1); //still works!`

Comment: @JesúsSánchez You can still use your original code, the example I posted is just a small sample of the code and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that will always be true, add it to your base virtual method to be enforced throughout your codebase.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByUsuarioId(int usuarioId)
{
    if (!typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IAuditable))
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>(); // per OffHeGoes' suggestion

    return _dbset.FindBy(c => c.UsuarioId == usuarioId);
}
```

Granted, per the comments below (and thank you all), there are both performance concerns and potential logic-hiding concerns with this solution.  It's hardly the most elegant way to solve the problem, but it does indeed solve it.

Comment: I would throw a NotImplementedException or something, as returning null is a misnomer.

Comment: @CBauer I completely agree.  That said, the OP's code is returning null and I prefer not to interpret his intent as to what he wants to return.

Comment: C Bauer, I have edited my original question, please check ...Thanks

Comment: Using reflection isn't the most elegant of solutions.  Now you need to know something about the inner logic of the method in order to be able to use it.

Comment: @JesúsSánchez I just mean that if another developer was to use your GenericRepository it may come as a surprise if the behaviour suddenly is different when T is IAuditable.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised by this *behaviour*, but I would be upset if I found reflection.

Comment: @CBauer Haha! I think technically it fails Liskov Substitution by returning null.  It *might* be ok if it instead returned `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are planning on *using* these repositories in your code (so this may not necessarily work with how you are consuming them), but why not add another layer of inheritance?

In your GenericRepository:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByUsuarioId(int usuarioId)
{
    //TODO: default behaviour
}
```

Then create a repository for the Auditable types:

```
public class AuditableRepository<T> : GenericRepository<T>
    where T: IAuditableEntity, BaseEntity
```

In which you implement the relevant logic:

```
public override IEnumerable<T> GetByUsuarioId(int usuarioId)
{
    //TODO: auditable behaviour
}
```

Obviously this does mean that you consuming code has to know about the different repositories, but as I say, it depends on how you are using them.  If you were using IoC you could inject the correct repositories.